# Use different icons for iphone 3gs & iphone 4 / 4s

Tags: iphone, image, icons

I have icons inside my application for uibutton & on uitable cell. Lets say I have image named "sampleImage.png". Can my app use the image named "sampleImage@2x.png iphone with retina display automatically provide it is in my app bundle ?
If yes how can write code for it because I have code like

cell.imageview.image = [UIImage named:@"sampleImage.png"];

Does it work even if I hardcoded the image name?

Any kind of help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: if your application bundle having sampleImage@2x.png already than it will automatically fetched when application will be run in the ratina display, no need to code for that. But do confirm one thing your image and image@2x name must be same always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for an answer of your question I came across this: [what is the code to detect whether ios app running in iPhone, iPhone Retina display, or iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217277/what-is-the-code-to-detect-whether-ios-app-running-in-iphone-iphone-retina-disp)

One of the answers mentions this:

> There's often no need to determine directly whether you're on a retina display because UIImage handles that automatically when you use imageNamed and append "@2x" to your high resolution image file names (see [Supporting High-Resolution Screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html) in the Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, UIImage will automatically use the @2x version of an image on a retina display.